# I want to hide woocommerce products from shop page using Post Id's

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide the **woo-commerce product from the shop page using Post Id's**. There were many different methods to hide from the shop page like **product_cat** etc.

**I want to hide the specific products from the shop page by passing the specific product id/ post id** !!

Answer (score 1):

Try following: using "pre_get_posts" hook

```
<?php

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'erginous_exclude_id' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

  if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
  if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;
  
  if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

    $q->set( 'post__not_in', array(70, 53) ); // Replace 70 and 53 with your products IDs. Separate each ID with a comma.
  
  }

  remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'erginous_exclude_id' );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for devoting your precious time to providing the solution..... but I wanna ask if this code works to hide the products from woocommerce shop page ??

Comment: Try  it in by adding it in functions.php file . It totally depends on your code .

Comment: Yeah, sir..... its works successfully for me...... Thank You !!